# Is this a correct use of the universal quantifier in a proof involving upper bounds?

Tags: proof-verification, logic, quantifiers

Introduction:

The underline notation $\underline{x},\underline{\mathcal{M}},$ is just "decoration" used to distinguish symbols. The + sign applied to sets means

$$\mathcal{M}+\underline{\mathcal{M}}\equiv \left\{x+ \underline{x}\backepsilon x\in\mathcal{M}\land\underline{x}\in\underline{\mathcal{M}}\right\}.$$

The $\backepsilon,$ meaning *such that*, is a commonly used alternative for $\vert.$ So

$$\left\{x+ \underline{x}\backepsilon x\in\mathcal{M}\land\underline{x}\in\underline{\mathcal{M}}\right\}\equiv
\left\{x+ \underline{x}\vert x\in\mathcal{M}\land\underline{x}\in\underline{\mathcal{M}}\right\}.$$

What follows addresses only part of a larger proof.  A screen-scrape of an older version of the proof is at the bottom of this post.  My question focuses on the first expression with a $\dagger$ next to it.

I begin with the proof, roughly as it is presented in [BBFSK](https://archive.org/stream/MyStuff38/Behnke%2C%20Bachmann%2C%20Fladt%20%26%20Suss%20%5BEds.%5D%20-%20Fundamentals%20of%20Mathematics%20Vol.1%2C%20The%20Real%20Number%20System%20and%20Algebra%5BMIT%20Press%2C%20555p%5D) Pages 137-138.  I then work progressively toward a modified version of the $\dagger$ statement which I believe to be more logically rigorous than the one appearing below.

---

Given some number set $\mathcal{M}$ we denote the set of upper bounds
of $\mathcal{M}$ by $\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{M}).$ Next we define the
set

$$\underline{\mathcal{M}}\equiv\left\{ \underline{x}\backepsilon-\underline{x}\in\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{M})\right\}.$$

Now we assume $z\in\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{M}+\underline{\mathcal{M}}).$
If $x\in\mathcal{M},$ and $\underline{x}\in\underline{\mathcal{M}}$
then $z\geq\underline{x}+x$, which means the same thing as $z-\underline{x}\in S(\mathcal{M}).$  This follows from the definition

$$\underline{x}\in\underline{\mathcal{M}}\iff-\underline{x}\in\mathcal{S}\left(\mathcal{M}\right)\iff\forall_{x\in\mathcal{M}}\left[-\underline{x}\ge x\right].$$

So

$$\left(\underline{x}\in\underline{\mathcal{M}}\land z\in\mathcal{S}\left(\mathcal{M}+\underline{\mathcal{M}}\right)\right)
\iff\forall_{x\in\mathcal{M}}\left[z\ge x+\underline{x}\right]
\iff\forall_{x\in\mathcal{M}}\left[z-\underline{x}\ge x\right].$$

That may be written as $z\geq\underline{x}+x\iff z-\underline{x}\in S(\mathcal{M}).$
So we have 
$$
\left(\left(x\in\mathcal{M}\land\underline{x}\in\underline{\mathcal{M}}\right)\implies z\geq\underline{x}+x\right)
$$

$$
\land\left(\left(x\in\mathcal{M}\land\underline{x}\in\underline{\mathcal{M}}\right)\implies\left(z\geq\underline{x}+x\iff z-\underline{x}\in S(\mathcal{M})\right)\right).
$$

We might state this as: for all $x\in\mathcal{M}$ and $\underline{x}\in\underline{\mathcal{M}}$
we have $z\geq\underline{x}+x,$ and $z\geq\underline{x}+x$ is equivalent
to $z-\underline{x}\in S(\mathcal{M}).$ Or: for all $x\in\mathcal{M}$
and $\underline{x}\in\underline{\mathcal{M}}$ we have $z\geq\underline{x}+x\iff z-\underline{x}\in S(\mathcal{M}).$
So why not use quantifier notation and write:

$$
\forall_{x\in\mathcal{M},\underline{x}\in\underline{\mathcal{M}}}\left[z\geq\underline{x}+x\iff z-\underline{x}\in S(\mathcal{M})\right]?
$$

In that form, it *looked* correct to me. But if we write the equivalent
statement

$$
\left(x\in\mathcal{M}\land\underline{x}\in\underline{\mathcal{M}}\right)\implies\left(z\geq\underline{x}+x\iff z-\underline{x}\in S(\mathcal{M})\right).
$$

It doesn't seem to have the intended meaning. This can be seen by
comparing truth tables.

Let

$A:=z\geq\underline{x}+x;$$B:=z-\underline{x}\in S(\mathcal{M});$and
$C:=x\in\mathcal{M}\land\underline{x}\in\underline{\mathcal{M}}.$

Then the truth table of $C\implies\left(A\iff B\right)$ is different
from that of $\left(C\implies A\right)\land\left(C\implies\left(A\iff B\right)\right).$

So 
$$
\forall_{x\in\mathcal{M},\underline{x}\in\underline{\mathcal{M}}}\left[z\geq\underline{x}+x\iff z-\underline{x}\in S(\mathcal{M})\right]
$$

doesn't mean the same thing as

$$
\forall_{x\in\mathcal{M},\underline{x}\in\underline{\mathcal{M}}}\left[z\geq\underline{x}+x\right]\land\left(z\geq\underline{x}+x\iff z-\underline{x}\in S(\mathcal{M})\right).
$$

But $x$ and $\underline{x}$ aren't bound in the second term, so
that really isn't the statement I want, either. A more accurate statement
would seem to be

$$
\forall_{x\in\mathcal{M},\underline{x}\in\underline{\mathcal{M}}}\left[z\geq\underline{x}+x\right]\land\forall_{x\in\mathcal{M},\underline{x}\in\underline{\mathcal{M}}}\left[z\geq\underline{x}+x\iff z-\underline{x}\in S(\mathcal{M})\right].
$$

But then, what about

$$
\forall_{x\in\mathcal{M},\underline{x}\in\underline{\mathcal{M}}}\left[\left(z\geq\underline{x}+x\right)\land\left(z\geq\underline{x}+x\iff z-\underline{x}\in S(\mathcal{M})\right)\right]?
$$

Are the last two statements equivalent? Does the last statement mean
the same thing as my original natural language statement? That is:
are $C\implies\left(A\land A\iff B\right)$ and $\left(C\implies A\right)\land\left(C\implies\left(A\iff B\right)\right)$
equivalent statements meaning the same thing as my original natural
language sentence?

The following is the truth table I generated to show
$$
\left(\left(C\implies A\right)\land\left(C\implies\left(A\iff B\right)\right)\right)\iff\left(C\implies\left(A\land A\iff B\right)\right).
$$

[image]

This is a screen-scrape of the version in my notes with which I began.  Note that I used $\overline{\mathcal{M}}$ instead of $\underline{\mathcal{M}}$.  The statements are not intended to be rigorously correct.  I was merely trying to capture my thought process.
[image]

Comment: "If $x\in\mathcal{M},$ and $\underline{x}\in\underline{\mathcal{M}}$
then $z\geq\underline{x}+x$, which means the same thing as $z-\underline{x}\in S(\mathcal{M}).$" No it doesn't.  Why do you think it does?

Comment: What is true is that "for all $x\in\mathcal{M}$, $z\geq \underline{x}+x$" means the same thing as "$z-\underline{x}\in S(\mathcal{M})$".  But that quantifier is crucial.

Comment: I believe my original statement is correct.  I added the details to the original post.

Comment: You lost me at $\underline{\mathcal{M}}\equiv\left\{ \underline{x}\backepsilon-\underline{x}\in\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{M})\right\}$. If this is valid notation, it's rather obscure. Then you follow that by using $+$ to denote an operation on two sets. Is that union? Direct sum? Something else?

Comment: @Acccumulation Please see the modifications to my original post for the meaning of my notation.

Comment: $\backepsilon$ is definitely not a "commonly used" symbol for "such that".  It is used with that meaning sometimes but it's quite rare.

Comment: It's common enough to be used here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/SuchThat.html  It's also used in BBFSK, and other sources either mention it as an alternative, or primarily use it.  When dealing with multi-variable calculus, absolute values, determinants and three or more different kinds of norms, vertical bars tend to get lost in the forest.  I reserve the colon specifically for mapping statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you express mathematical statements using propositional logic variables, you abstract away from the meaning of those statements. Thus, relationships that hold true in the original mathematical domain may no longer hold true in propositional logic.

For example, once we symbolize the mathematical statements $x>1$ and $x \leq 1$ as $A$ and $B$ respectively, it is no longer the case that exactly one of these statements is true. That is, when we do a truth-table analysis on $A$ and $B$, we find that there is a row where both are true, as well as a row where both are false, but obviously, as mathematical statements, neither of those can happen.

In other words, it is possible that your logical analysis does not match up with the mathematical analysis.

I suspect something like this is going on in your example, though my math skills aren't good enough to understand the reasoning you went through in your post.

Comment: I know what you mean about trying to formulate mathematical statement using propositional logic.  There are often additional constraints on the truth values of the component terms.  But I take that to mean that I haven't identified all the logical dependencies.  So, my magic $C\implies (A\land B)$ may, in fact be correct given the context.  One of my goals in using the quantifier notation is to formalize the scoping (in the computer science sense) of variables and assertions.  When I formulate "magic" statements, that means there are contributing "global" variables and assertions.

Comment: I will add that if our mathematical statements and logical statements appear to be in conflict, then we have failed to capture the essence of the problem at hand.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton Agreed ... but not too surprising, given how much propositional logic 'throws away' in its abstractions